# Does calling a member from an object that is lvalue return lvalue?

Tags: c++

I am studying C++ primer 5th edition by Lipman and I have a question. In that book is written:

> The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue; otherwise the result is an rvalue.

```
string x = "Hello World";
x.size() = 20; // I get an error saying that left-hand operand should be an l-
               //  value
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: It says dot, not `size()`, but I agree that this is somewhat confusing.

Comment: look it talks about that size() example

explaining p -> size() // p is a pointer to string

Comment: and says that arrow operator returns lvalue

Comment: `x.size()` is a function call expression. `x.size` is a class member access, but it's not quite useful to know whether `x.size` is an lvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the member is fetched is an lvalue;otherwise the result is an rvalue."

This is relevant when the member is an object, not a function.

Let's say you have:

```
struct Foo
{
   int a;
};

Foo bar() { return Foo{}; }
```

and use `Foo` and `bar` as:

```
int main()
{
    Foo f1;  // f1 is an lvalue.
    f1.a = 10;   // Valid. f1 is an lvalue. Implies that f1.a is an lvalue.

    bar();   // The object returned is not an lvalue.
    bar().a = 20; // Not vaild since bar().a is not an lvalue.
}
```

In your case,

```
x.size() = 20;
```

fails not because `x` is not an lvalue but because `x.size()` returns an object that is not an lvalue.

Answer (score 3):

> "The dot operator yields an lvalue if the object from which the **member** is fetched is an lvalue;otherwise the result is an rvalue."

`std::string::size()` is not a member, but method so your example does not follow the statement.

Note: we can have discussion if we can call method a member in this sense. This is questionable, but citation then would apply to member function itself, not the result of the call which relies on different rules. Maybe we can discuss if  `x.size` is an lvalue or not(which does not make much sense as you cannot assign to pointer to member function or standalone one), but this rule definitely would not apply to `x.size()`

Look like though this statement is simplified for clarity, for example "otherwise the result is an rvalue" is not quite correct as it is actually `xvalue`:

> a.m, the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of non-reference type;

Details can be found here [value category](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

Comment: Yes, it is a member. A member function, specifically.

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer. The key in the statement is the difference between lvalue and rvalue. The used method is simply a rvalue. There are methods which can be used as lvalue.

Comment: @MarcusS you cannot use member function as an lvalue syntactically so it is irrelevant is `x.size` an lvalue or not, but this cannot apply to the result of a function call.

Comment: @Slava You can use methods as lvalue when they are returning a reference.

Comment: @MarcusS yes you can use result of a function (member or not) call as lvalue in some cases, how is that related to the question and how that makes my answer incorrect?

Comment: In your original answer, which is still the first part of your answer, are you talking about the function itself, or its result? If you are contesting that the function itself is not a member, C++ parlance (derived from the original books on C++, and now embedded in the standard itself) disagrees. What some other languages call methods, are (and have have always been) called member functions in C++. If you're instead referring to the result of the function, I've never heard anyone, in any language, refer to the result of the function as a method.

Comment: So either way, I don't see the relevance of the first part of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

The error message complains about the *result* of `x.size()`, and not about `x` or `x.size()` itself. And the result (`std::string::size_type`) is not a l-value but an r-value.

Comment: Not sure, but I would rather guess, it's an [`xvalue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#xvalue) or plain rvalue.

Comment: Returning by value returns a prvalue

Comment: "a function call or an overloaded operator expression, whose return type is non-reference, such as " that is from `prvalue`